# To find the equation of a space curve given a curvature and torsion function in terms of the angle between the Darboux vector and the tangent

Tags: differential-geometry

If a space curve $\gamma(s)$ parametrised with respect to arc length $ s $ has curvature as  $$\kappa(s) = \cos^{2} (\theta(s))$$ and torsion as $$\tau(s) =  \sin(\theta(s) ) \cos(\theta(s)) ,$$ where  $ \theta(s) $ is a function that gives the angle between the tangent vector to the curve and it's Darboux vector i.e. $ \tau T + \kappa B $ , 
then is there a way of getting the possible parametrisation of such a curve or even $\textbf{an example of such a curve}$??

Of course, apart from the circular helix, in which case the function $\theta $ is a constant.

$\textbf{Note}$ : The angle $\theta(s)$ is actually the angle between the tangent to $\gamma$ and the tangent vector of another curve which is $1-1$ correspondence with $\gamma$, however that tangent vector is itself parallel to the Darboux vector, so I have defined it as such.

Comment: Do you mean a curve for which $\kappa$ and $\tau$ satisfy the given conditions? If so, you shouldn't expect many solutions: We can write $\cos^2 \theta$ and $\sin \theta \cos \theta$ as functions of $\kappa$ and $\theta$, giving a system of two equations in two unknowns, which generically has finite many solutions. In that case, $\kappa$ and $\tau$ must be locally constant, so one expects the only solutions to be certain helices.

Comment: @Travis Yes. I did mean the same. But I didnt get why they would be helices as that would force $\theta$ to be a constant, right?? By locally constant, did you mean, like a curve patched together by helices of different radius?

Comment: So, if one carries out the computation I described, you get the solutions $\kappa = \frac{1}{2}$, $\tau = \pm \frac{1}{2}$. But the only curves with constant curvature and torsion are helices. In fact, that this is the solution to the system shows that there's only a single solution up to Euclidean motions (allowing reflections).

Comment: @Travis. Well the curvature and torsion functions seem to satisfy a relation like $\kappa^2 +\tau^2 = \kappa$ and I could think of non-helical curves too which satisfy that relation. So I presumed there may be other curves than the helix. Also I didn't get as to how you ended with those values. The varying angle condition seems to be vacuously satisfied then.  But the fundamental theorem seems to hint that s not the case, right?